# Image in JSON iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

I try to get an image in `JSON`, but how can I get the image into a `NSData`?
All I get is an `__NSCFArray` with my binary data, but how to convert it?

EDIT:
This is my result in json

```
Printing description of resDict:
{
Details = "Foo";
GroupingInfo = LRU;
HeaderLeft = "Bar";
HeaderRight = "Foo";
Id = "cb217aeb-14e3-4bd5-8895-3217238deb2c";
IsGray = 0;
AnotherId = "<null>";
MainImage =     (
    137,
    80,
    78,
    71,
 ...
```

Comment: Where do you get your JSON from? Could you show an example? An `NSArray` is a pretty unusual representation of image data. Also: Show your code!

Comment: I parse the json and retrieve my data. But the JSON Tag where the image was is only an array of int's (?) and I cant get them into a nsdata.

Comment: Show an example of your JSON structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first have to parse the JSON, then take the binary part, into NSData. UIImage has a method to do change NSData into image

```
UIImage *myimage = [UIImage imageWithData:mydata];
```

Update : (hope no one minds)
After making myself such a demo, NSJSONSerialization always returns strings, and after having a small back and forth conversation below. I tried to send an image as a Base64 coded string and read back in as data using base64 decode. This works as a charm.

This is the code I use (since this works on all iOS versions, from 3.0 and up) :

NSData+PHBase64.h

```
@interface NSData (PHBase64)

+ (id)dataWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string;     //  Padding '=' characters are optional. Whitespace is ignored.
- (NSString *)base64Encoding;
@end
```

NSData+PHBase64.m

```
#import "NSData+Base64.h"


static const char encodingTable[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";


@implementation NSData (PHBase64)

+ (id)dataWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string;
{
    if (string == nil)
        [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:nil];
    if ([string length] == 0)
        return [NSData data];

    static char *decodingTable = NULL;
    if (decodingTable == NULL)
    {
        decodingTable = malloc(256);
        if (decodingTable == NULL)
            return nil;
        memset(decodingTable, CHAR_MAX, 256);
        NSUInteger i;
        for (i = 0; i < 64; i++)
            decodingTable[(short)encodingTable[i]] = i;
    }

    const char *characters = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    if (characters == NULL)     //  Not an ASCII string!
        return nil;
    char *bytes = malloc((([string length] + 3) / 4) * 3);
    if (bytes == NULL)
        return nil;
    NSUInteger length = 0;

    NSUInteger i = 0;
    while (YES)
    {
        char buffer[4];
        short bufferLength;
        for (bufferLength = 0; bufferLength < 4; i++)
        {
            if (characters[i] == '\0')
                break;
            if (isspace(characters[i]) || characters[i] == '=')
                continue;
            buffer[bufferLength] = decodingTable[(short)characters[i]];
            if (buffer[bufferLength++] == CHAR_MAX)      //  Illegal character!
            {
                free(bytes);
                return nil;
            }
        }

        if (bufferLength == 0)
            break;
        if (bufferLength == 1)      //  At least two characters are needed to produce one byte!
        {
            free(bytes);
            return nil;
        }

        //  Decode the characters in the buffer to bytes.
        bytes[length++] = (buffer[0] << 2) | (buffer[1] >> 4);
        if (bufferLength > 2)
            bytes[length++] = (buffer[1] << 4) | (buffer[2] >> 2);
        if (bufferLength > 3)
            bytes[length++] = (buffer[2] << 6) | buffer[3];
    }

    realloc(bytes, length);
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:bytes length:length];
}

- (NSString *)base64Encoding;
{
    if ([self length] == 0)
        return @"";

  char *characters = malloc((([self length] + 2) / 3) * 4);
    if (characters == NULL)
        return nil;
    NSUInteger length = 0;

    NSUInteger i = 0;
    while (i < [self length])
    {
        char buffer[3] = {0,0,0};
        short bufferLength = 0;
        while (bufferLength < 3 && i < [self length])
            buffer[bufferLength++] = ((char *)[self bytes])[i++];

        //  Encode the bytes in the buffer to four characters, including padding "=" characters if necessary.
        characters[length++] = encodingTable[(buffer[0] & 0xFC) >> 2];
        characters[length++] = encodingTable[((buffer[0] & 0x03) << 4) | ((buffer[1] & 0xF0) >> 4)];
        if (bufferLength > 1)
            characters[length++] = encodingTable[((buffer[1] & 0x0F) << 2) | ((buffer[2] & 0xC0) >> 6)];
        else characters[length++] = '=';
        if (bufferLength > 2)
            characters[length++] = encodingTable[buffer[2] & 0x3F];
        else characters[length++] = '=';    
    }

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:characters length:length encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding freeWhenDone:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: The problem is the part where the data is, is only an __NSCFArray.
I get the rest of my data without problems of it but I dont know how I can turn the array into an nsdata.

Comment: If you could show your json structure, it would help. But you can always just typecast, NSData *mydata = [[myjson valueForKey:@"image"] data];

Comment: The example is in my edit. When I try to cast to NSData I get -[__NSCFArray data]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Wish I could try out a few things on your json feed. What about NSData *mydata = (NSData *)[mydict valueForKey:@"MainImage"]; ?

Comment: I use the NSJSONSerialization, I try the other thing later

Comment: Are you using "NSJSONReadingAllowFragments" as a parameter ?

Comment: I try it on monday, got no apple currently here

Comment: Any news on this ? I actually have the exact same problem here on Cocoa. Uploading NSData of an image, but when I download it, I get it as NSString, and it just refuses to convert into NSImage

Comment: No sorry, the image is now sent as a base64 string in the json data and this works perfectly

Comment: Well, that is a solution. Thanks

Comment: But not really for this problem :)